# Posting Div values in Spring Controller

Tags: java, jquery, spring

I am using https://github.com/puikinsh/gentelella template for small java project. Part of that I am using Calendar range selection where I am unable to send the selected date range to Spring Controller class. Below code gives me a Calendar and I am able to select the values but onclick or submit I am unable to send the values back to my Controller. Can you please help?

***JSP Code:***

```
<form id="demo-form2" data-parsley-validate="" class="form-horizontal form-label-left"
   novalidate="" action="txnsummeryDetails">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Report Date
      Range</label>
      <div id="reportrange_right" class="pull-left"
         style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc">
         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>
         <span id="dateStr">May 4, 2017 - June 2, 2017</span> <b class="caret"></b>
      </div>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button onclick="function submitForm() {
         var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('datatable-buttons');
         alert(MyDiv1);
         }
         submitForm()" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

***Controller Code:***

```
@RequestMapping(value = "txnsummeryDetails", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView txnSummeryFormHandler() {
        List<TransactionsSummary> txnDetails = transactionsSummaryService.getTxnDetails("28-05-17", "31-05-17");
        return new ModelAndView("txnSummery", "txnDetails", txnDetails);
    }
```

Comment: So, are you posting with HTTP GET method? I'm seeing many problems with your jsp as well as controller code. No, `@ModelAttribute` or `@PathVariable` passed as arguments to  `txnSummeryFormHandler` method in controller to read form params and also in `form` tag am not seeing `method="POST"`. If you send form data with GET, it spams the url with the form data. If you have password in that form, gone!

Comment: Hi, I am  submitting a request variable so GET should do fine. All I am lost is capturing and sending the selected value on JSP.